# c# N-tier architecture - should the BL or presentation layer know about custom types in DataLayer

Tags: c#, n-tier-architecture

I'm creating a 3-tier solution comprising of the box standard projects: DAL, BLL, Presentation layer.

There are some custom types in my DAL such as:

```
public class Clients 
{
public int Id {get;set}
public string Firstname {get;set;}
public string Surname {get;set;
}
```

What is the best approach to push this custom type up the stack to the presentation layer. Is it common practice for the BL and presentation to reference models from my DAL?  Or should I look at generic interfaces so that the BLL can accept/consume a `List <T>` for example?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at [eShop on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb), and read the architecture parts of the eBook even if your app isn't for the Web.

Comment: Thank you Henk, that is exactly what I needed :o)

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging it looks like DTOs are my best route.  So I'll create a new project to hold custom object types aka business objects.  This project will in turn be referenced by my DAL, BLL and presentation layer.

Comment: DTOs don't jump of the page here, but you didn't specify the Project type in any detail.

Comment: Why would you put ‘business objects’ anywhere but the BLL?